# cannot access field on a value with type string_google big query

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

I faced an error in google big query that I haven't been successful to find a solution for that.

I have two tables, `Airnow_dataset.adjustedTime_met_la_wind_letter` and `Airnow_dataset.station_neighbour`,  the value of `wind_direction` column in the former table defines the column name of the latter one.

I used "case" clause to refer to the appropriate columns of another table, but an error comes up whenever I run query

> cannot access field pm_station on a value with type string at [3:83]

I would like to mention that the number of rows returned in `station_neighbour` is one, so it shouldn't be a problem. Also, when I hardcoded `s.pm_station value`, it works fine. I guess the problem is due to aliasing in the outer query, but I don't know how I can fix it. For your information, I have attached the screenshot of my tables as well as my code.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is my query:

```
SELECT s.pm_station, s.RH, (CASE 
                        WHEN s.wind_direction="W" then (SELECT ss.W FROM 
                       `Airnow_dataset.station_neighbour` ss 
                        WHERE ss.pm_station=s.pm_station ) 
                        ELSE "na" 
                        END) as neighbour_wind_direction
FROM `Airnow_dataset.adjustedTime_met_la_wind_letter` s
```

This is image of schemas:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `station_neighbour` table has a column named `S`, so the outer alias for `adjustedTime_met_la_wind_letter` is shadowed within the `CASE WHEN` expression. To work around the error, use a different alias, e.g.:

```
SELECT
  wind_letter.pm_station,
  wind_letter.RH,
  (CASE WHEN wind_letter.wind_direction="W" THEN (
       SELECT ss.W FROM 
       `Airnow_dataset.station_neighbour` ss 
       WHERE ss.pm_station=wind_letter.pm_station ) 
   ELSE "na" END) as neighbour_wind_direction
FROM `Airnow_dataset.adjustedTime_met_la_wind_letter` wind_letter
```